# How does Apache detects a stopped Tomcat JVM?

Tags: apache, tomcat, load-balancing, httpd.conf

We are running multiple Tomcat JVMs under a single Apache cluster. If we shut down all the JVMs except one, sometime we get 503s. If we increase the
retry interval to 180(from retry=10), problem goes away. That bring me
to this question, how does Apache detects a stopped Tomcat JVM? If I
have a cluster which contains multiple JVMs and some of them are down,
how Apache finds that one out? Somewhere I read, Apache uses a real
request to determine health of a back end JVM. In that case, will that
request failed(with 5xx) if JVM is stopped? Why higher retry value is
making the difference? Do you think introducing ping might help?

If someone can explain a bit or point me to some doc, that would be awesome.

We are using Apache 2.4.10, mod_proxy, byrequests LB algorithm, sticky session,
keepalive is on and ttl=300 for all balancer members.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well let's examine a little what your configuration is actually doing in action and then move to what might help.

[[docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)]

`retry` - Here either you 've set it `10` or `180` what you specify is how much time apache will consider your backend server down and thus won't send him requests. So the higher the value, you gain the time for your backend to get up completely but you put more load to the others since you are -1 server for more time.

`stickysession` - Here if you lose a backend server for whatever reason all the sessions are on it get an error.

All right now that we described the relevant variables for your situation let's clear that *apache mod_proxy does not have a health check mechanism embedded*, it updates the status of your backend based on responses on real requests.

So your current configuration works as following:

1. Request arrives on apache
2. Apache send it to an alive backend
3. If request gets an error http code for response or doesn't get a response at all, apache puts that backend in ERROR state.
4. After retry time is passed apache sends to that backend server requests again.

So reading the above you understand that the first request that will reach a backend server which is down will get an error page.

One of the things you can do is indeed `ping`, according to the docs will check the backend before send any request. Consider of course the overhead that produces.

Although I would suggest you to configure [mod_proxy_ajp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) which is offering extra functionality (and configuration ofc) to your tomcat backend failover detection.

Comment: :I tried `ping` with `retry=10` but that did not made any difference. I still can easily reproduce 503 errors. Another thing I noticed while going through the `error.log`. If I have 10 Tomcat JVMs and 9 of them are down and my good JVM is on 7th position in the list; then for 6 stopped JVMs Apache prints following error: `AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: xxx` one by one until it reaches to the good JVM which is up. But request did not failed. Again, what puzzles me is this works fine if I set `retry=180` or `retry=60`. With `retry=10`, it fails 90% of the time.

Comment: For how long do you perform tests? Do you send requests lets say for 900 sec ? Plus ping: `For HTTP, it causes mod_proxy_http to send a 100-Continue to the backend (only valid for HTTP/1.1 - for non HTTP/1.1 backends, this property has no effect)` this is from docs, that's I suggested ajp (I know nothing for your backend besided jvm).

Comment: @zochmax Yes, we are using mod_proxy_http, so `ping` will work. We ran all tests for 2-3 hours. I am planning to turn on more logging in Apache to understand this behavior.

Comment: @suv3ndu Yes in this situation debug level log is helpful. As for the `ping`  in order to work properly your backend (not only to use `mod_proxy_http`) have to be HTTP/1.1.

Comment: After turning on debug logging in Apache I found the answer of why retry=180 works but retry=10 fails. It is primarily about `maxattempts`. For us it is 35 by default. If retry value is 10, then workers gets disabled and re-enabled by Apache pretty frequently and in searching for a good worker Apache quickly passing 35 attempts – resulting failure. When we are setting retry value to 180, Apache is enabling a disabled worker after long time. Hence chances to get a good worker increases significantly with lesser number of fail-over attempts. That is preventing 503s from occurring.

Comment: I am still in search for a good health-checking method. [mod_proxy_hcheck](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_hcheck.html) works but it is not full proof. During my tests I have seen that sometimes it marks down good JVMs. :)